# Madcow IRC bot python error Windows 7

Tags: python, windows

I installed python 2.7, pip installed and django installed. when I go to run the standalone command I keep getting this error

```
A fatal error ocurred
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\madcow\madcow\__init__.py", line 833, in run
    protocol(base).start()
  File "C:\madcow\madcow\protocol\irc.py", line 19, in __init__
    super(IRCProtocol, self).__init__(base, scheme=COLOR_SCHEME)
  File "C:\madcow\madcow\__init__.py", line 100, in __init__
    signal.signal(signal.SIGHUP, self.signal_handler)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SIGHUP'
```

Comment: It's a bug in MadCow, if nothing else.

Comment: With apologies for the initial, wrong, assumption on my part.

Answer (score 1):

The `signal` signal constants are platform dependant; the Windows OS doesn't *have* a `SIGHUP` signal so there is no `signal.SIGHUP` attribute either.

The [MadCow source code](https://github.com/cjones/madcow/blob/master/madcow/__init__.py) does try to handle this, but does it incorrectly:

```
# be mindful of win32
try:
    import signal
except ImportError:
    signal = None
```

Note the comment. However, even on Windows the `signal` module can be imported; the available signals just differ.

Until a few years ago, it [**used** to do it correctly](https://github.com/cjones/madcow/blob/8061fe6d565a9c584a7e93a230a8142972991961/madcow/__init__.py):

```
# be mindful of win32
try:
    from signal import signal, SIGHUP, SIGTERM, SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN
    SIGNALS = True
except ImportError:
    SIGNALS = False
```

This will correctly raise an exception on Windows platforms.

You may want to file a [bug report](https://github.com/cjones/madcow/issues) to that effect.